# Allow PPTPD Clients to Communicate

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, routing, remote

Ive set up a PPTPD VPN server on an Ubuntu 12.04 Machine. I have 3 machines connected to it, 2 of which are on the same network and one that is on a separate network. All 3 are on the VPN, and can ping each other. I cant remote into any of the computers from each other. None of the computers are using the VPN as a gateway, and it is simply used to give me remote access to my home computers when I am not home as my ISP blocks RDP. I can access the VPN server itself from its Internal VPN Ip (192.168.5.1), but cant access any of the other 3 (192.168.5.100-103)

Comment: you probably need static routes, but you need to give more precise informations if you want to know exactly which routes are needed.

Comment: What information would I need to provide?

Comment: explain the ip addressing / network configuration of your different servers

Comment: I have a main desk computer at home with address 192.168.5.101
I have another computer acting as a router using windows server at the same location at 192.168.5.100
I have 1 computer at my work location with ip address 192.168.5.102.
The computer acting as a router is using windows server 2012 and is set up for DHCP, DNS and NAT. This does the routing for my entire home including my Main Computer. The VPN server is set up using the amazon cloud service. None of the computers are requesting an ip, so it is all dynamic at the moment.

Comment: Can you ping from 192.168.5.100 to 192.168.5.102 , and vice-versa?

Comment: Yes, pinging from any works fine and I get replies in around 40ms on average.

Comment: ok so this is your win2K12 server which acts as a firewall I suppose. i thought you were running on pptpd/linux, can't help you for win2k12, sorry.

Comment: I am running on pptpd and linux for the VPN, the windows server does my IP addresses at home, and the firewall wont be a problem whatsoever. All the requests get to the PPtPD server (the amazon cloud, ubuntu one) and then don't get forwarded to other machines on the system.

Comment: "The computer acting as a router is using windows server 2012"?

Comment: Yes, a router, at home. Not my VPN, the one providing my HOME address, with access to the internet. It doesnt have anything to do with the VPN machine and for all intents and purposes it could easily by a netgear router, as that is all it does.

Comment: if the server is linux pptpd, check your iptables configuration.

Comment: This is what I don't know how to do, the pptpd server is the one that the vpn is set up on. Its assigning IP's to new machines but I dont know how to do the IP tables to allow access through the vpn?